# Testing HTML4 / CSS2 / JavaScript in 2017?

Tags: css, testing, html4

Apologies in advance if this is the wrong forum for this question - if it is, please suggest an alternative and I'll flag this post to be moved there.

I've been working on a project where an engine is used, that can render HTML4 / CSS2. I'd like to possibly outsource some of the HTML design externally, but it's likely I will not be able to create an application that uses this engine, which the developers could use to check if they are writing code that this engine can parse.

So, I would like to instruct the hired developers to deliver HTML4 / CSS2 design; however, if they work in modern browsers, then it is possible some HTML5 / CSS3 syntax will leak in, which means that once I put their code in the engine, I'll have the problem of translating HTML5 / CSS3 idioms down to HTML4 / CSS2.

That is why, I'd like to know, what possibilities do I have for testing HTML4 / CSS2 these days (2017):

- Maybe there are command line switches that can be issued to modern Firefox / Chromium, so that they go into a HTML4 / CSS2 rendering mode?
- If not, maybe the best is to download an older version of the browser; however what are the last versions of (say) Firefox or Chromium that worked only in HTML4/CSS2?

Note that I'd rather avoid services like http://browsershots.org/ or https://www.browserstack.com/ - or even online services that might emulate HTML4/CSS2 by use of extra JavaScript libraries (if such services exist).

Comment: Why not just replace that engine with something more modern? All platforms offer UI controls that can be used to render web content. To maintain something like that yourself is crazy if not for educational purposes only.

Comment: You can also just validate the code against the old HTML 4 DOCTYPE and CSS2(.1). There is no single browser in existence that fully and exclusively supports HTML 4 and CSS2(.1) (not even IE8, because IE8 supports things like substring-matching attribute selectors, the ~ combinator, and box-sizing, none of which are part of CSS2).

Comment: thanks @MarioDS - because replacing that engine with something more modern would likely extend the development time by months, which is something the project cannot afford right now...

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, good to keep that in mind; any links about how to validation is performed? Also, could one count on older version of browsers to support HTML4 and CSS2 exclusively, if one cannot count on modern browsers to do so?

Comment: I said that no browser exists that does so. I probably should have said "no version of any browser exists", but they mean the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @BoltClock:  "no version of any browser exists" made it clear to me now!